# Why doesn't this invalid syntax throw an error?

Tags: javascript

I would expect the code below to throw a syntax error, because of `'some string' [{}]`, but it just works fine. Although the property is `undefined`.

```js
const object = {
  property: 'some string' [{}]
}

console.log(object)
```

This on the other hand throws an error as expected:

```js
const object = {
  property: 'some string' []
}

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first is not invalid syntax. That code is looking for a property `[object Object]` (the `{}` is cast to a string).

The second is invalid syntax, because there is nothing in property access operator.

Note, however, that because this is `string` and not `String`, you cannot add custom properties yourself.

You can still lookup properties, because there is `.length` and also things on the prototype such as `.slice()` and `.substring()`

For example, if you add the custom property to the prototype, you can cheese this:

```js
String.prototype["[object Object]"] = "banana";

const object = {
  property: 'some string' [{}]
}

console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are really just attempting access on the string like this (with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)):

```js
property: 'some string'[{}]
```

Anything between the two brackets is evaluated and coerced to a string, so you'll actually get:

```js
property: 'some string'['[object Object]']
```

and as we all know, strings do not have a `[object Object]` property.

Your second example is invalid, because there must be something between the brackets when using bracket notation.